# WAR LESS Deployment of multiple GRADLE projects using EMBEDDED JETTY Server

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jetty, war

I have a main JAVA project with an **Embedded** JETTY server. I need to deploy multiple **Gradle** Projects using this embedded jetty server.

I am looking for a **WAR** **LESS** deployment of all projects. The concept is described in this [LINK](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/08/23/war-less-java-web-apps).

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();

    root.setContextPath("/");
    root.setDescriptor(webappDirLocation + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    root.setResourceBase(webappDirLocation);

    root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

    server.setHandler(root);

    server.start();
    server.join();
  }
```

But it is **Not** working (I was getting lots of **ClassNotFoundException**(s) on the inluded Gradle projects) when i tried for **Gradle** projects.

I am using Spring Tool Suite IDE (eclipse). Help me guys.

Comment: what do you mean by "Not working"? did u get any error messages while starting the jetty server? the link you have posted is for maven and not for gradle..

Comment: @Lucky - I was getting lots of dependency errors while invoking the Gradle project using the method above(BUT the same Gradle project is working fine if i build it directly through Gradle). If you know any workaround let me know.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/jhannes/java-ee-turnkey/ for size.

Comment: @judoole, am looking for a war less deployment through embedded jetty server.

Comment: @OMG war/jar is a little potato/potato in this case. The repo linked is an embedded jetty, only the artifact is a war which you run with java -jar my-fantastic-app.war

Comment: What is in your build script?

Comment: at little out dated..but give this a try..https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-gradle and https://github.com/jesperfj/hello-gradle